# remove muse maintenance page from existing opencart site

Tags: php, ftp, adobe, opencart, muse

I'm currently using opencart 2x to build my website, but wanted a nicer looking maintenance page while it was being worked on due to it getting a considerable number of searches, and wanting to hide the theme work while it was being ironed out.

I created a page in adobe muse cc and uploaded it via ftp onto the server, just to public_html. Fool on me because I realised I can now see the admin area but not the site, forgetting that opencart's maintencance mode filter would not apply.

I have combed through google trying to find a fix of how to remove the page made in muse so I can implement it some other way, and have tried searching for it's assets in my FTP program. I am not entirely comfortable in making blind edits to important configuration files as I have put considerable work into this site already.

Comment: Did you make a backup of your site before you updated it? Did you try deleting the page you uploaded? Have you made any changes that you haven't told us about?

Comment: @jmarkmurphy The site backs up automatically as far as I am aware, but that's more or less what I'm having trouble with - deleting the page, as i dont think opencart lists it as a page I can delete or edit through the backend so I'm guessing its a manual FTP job? Haven't removed anything just yet though!

Answer (score 0):

This has been closed by going into cpanel and comparing the public_html files with those of a backup from earlier & deleting the differences, should have been my first port of call and I never thought to do it, whoops.